# jQuery.before formatting text from the CSS

Tags: jquery

I am using `jQuery.before` to put text into my web app via javascript

The text is displaying but not formatted by CSS of the HTML file

How do you make `jQuery.before` follow the CSS formatting

I have tried `document.getElementById('div name').innerHTML=string` with text and jQuery formats

How should I be doing it?

Comment: Can we see some HTML and Javascript code ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem (at least the way I understand your issue) with jQuery itself. Here is an example i've created: -
http://jsfiddle.net/pw4S5/ Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this and get CSS formatting:

```
$('<div/>')
    .html('<p>My message here.</p>')
    .insertBefore('#mydiv');
```

This should inject like this:

```
<div><p>My message here.</p></div>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

The trick is injecting html code and not plain text.

Comment: This code makes no difference  I text is raw and as per the CSS

Comment: the issue turned out to be I needed  .trigger("create")   jQuery.before(the id name).html(html string).trigger("create")

Comment: Oh, ok, the issue then being that the element had not yet been created? The "create" event fires when an element is created, so when you trigger it, then it can apply the css -- I'm guessing.